# Simple LDAP 7.x-2.0-alpha1+3-dev

Tags: authentication-authorization

Is this a stable version? I am having to many troubles trying to configure Simple LDAP 7.x.02. It recognize my domain controller but it doesn't talk to it.

Does anyone has a suggestion to have a better configuration? 
Or any other module that configure LDAP on Drupal 7 ??

Thanks
[image]

Comment: It says "alpha" and "dev" in version numner, right? Nothing with "dev", "alpha", "beta" or "rc" in name can be considered stable.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bugreport for development version of a module, and should be reported in appropriate issue queue, not here.

Comment: Apologize for starting the paragraph with "Is this a stable version?" 
I am looking to see if that module has worked out for any Drupal7 user, and gather some configuration help to lead me back in track.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're having a bind issue, I don't know how that module works but did you give it a service account and password to use?

I have used the [LDAP](https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap) module successfully.  It has many options so it can look a bit scary but it has very good documentation.

Comment: Thanks for that answer Darvanen. I am pretty new to drupal and its modules. I haven't try LDAP yet, mainly because it was in beta for Druapl 7, same as SimpleLdap. But I will try it aswell. I don't get scare, but sometimes lost =( . Which beta version have you tried? 7.x.1 or 7.x.2?? 
Thanks again.

Comment: Definitely go with 2, I don't really know why is still in beta, for simple applications at least it works quite well